# jQuery with .Net

Tags: jquery, .net

So I have a very simple .Net page that uses JQuery. When I place the code directly on the page the script executes fine, but when I call from an external js page it fails.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#MainContent_Button1").click(function () {
        alert("Hello world!");
    });

});
(jQuery)

<asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="Button1" runat="server" Text="CLICK ME FOO" />
```

When I link like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>.
```

It doesn't work, but if I place on the page it works fine.

Comment: what do you mean .. when i call it from an external page?

Comment: You mean when you have the `$(function() {..})` in an external JS file? When do you load the external file?

Comment: Use the IE9, Chrome or Firefox Firebug console to troubleshoot. You haven't provided enough information to actually answer, but my guess is you're including the above jQuery code before you include jQuery itself.

Comment: @MoXplod When I link like so: <script type="text/javascript" href="menu.js"></script>. It doesn't work but if I place on the page it works fine.

Comment: @Dave Yes when the function is in an external JS file it bonks out. I know the function works as well as the direct path to it. I don't get it. But I've tried loading in the header and in the document.

Comment: Either that, or your path to your file is not right. Or it's both.

Comment: Again, the order of loading is important, and we still don't know.

Comment: For instance, in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel), open your page with Firebug open, click on the Script tab, and then look for the part that has the filename ([here](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/images/4/46/Script_Panel.png) it's *del-linkrolls.js*). Click that and you'll see all the included files. Select the problem one and see if shows any code. If not, check the Net tab on refresh and see if the file downloads or gives an error.

Answer (score 1):

It's supposed to be src="" in the script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>
```

Comment: ... or, the include itself is not right... (See comments below question.) Note, this is why I use Firebug to check to make sure the file is downloading.

Comment: Right. I mis-typed here but sure src="".

Comment: @Ricky - You're going to have to provide evidence for us to check. Use a console function in one of the browsers that support to make sure the file is downloading.

Comment: This is my entire code.


    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="CLICK ME FOO" />
    </div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>

When I place the function where the link is it works fine.

Comment: @Ricky Maybe the question would be the best place to put that.

Comment: And where is the menu.js file located? Is it in the same folder? Is it on the server? Or are you running locally?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the javascript file you are referencing externally is not loading.  Use chrome to make sure you are getting a 200 message for that file and not a 404.  Also, make sure in your external javascript file you are including the jquery document load method exactly like you have above.  You have to ensure the button has been placed in the DOM before you can bind any events to it.  Also I would recommending using ClientIDMode="static" so you can reference the button with the actual id of button in the jQuery selector.